# Snowflake put command throws HTTPError('400 Client Error: Bad Request for url - )

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am receiving below error while using put command and uploading file on snowflake.

It is Error 400
It works for other files but fails for only one file with below error.

Error  link - https://sfc-uk-ds1-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com/drko-s-ukss0127/tables/2323577421858/FACT_RFM_SEGMENTATION.csv?partNumber=83&uploadId=PosKnuUecwKdJdFOQopotAdcwdk2IJ2wtgwsrvbDD_mSas7L.vD.7Bz8bXX1M_QAZKyVWiaxdf5I6ime9FWSwQHI0BpV17WGVRgfpMSd5_hhm92jNGI3a2JrRiTvsblz

Snowflake Put command -

```
user_details#XSMALL_WHSE@DEV_DB.FACT>put file://D:\snowflake\lab_db_csv_files\file_name.csv @"FACT".%"table_name" auto_compress=False;
```

I tried with both Auto_compress False and True. but it is not working in any case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I remember one of the versions had an issue with the PUT command.

Check your current version by running:

```
snowsql --version
```

Then try to use different versions:

```
snowsql --version 1.2.18
```

Above command will launch SnowSQL using version 1.2.18, then test again.

Comment: but it is working for other files. I have loaded around 30+ files till now. and this command is not working on command line